# How can make CMake install an external project my targets depend on?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am developing an application and have separated some functionality into a second repository. I want to

1. Make the library repo a git submodule since both will be developed side-by-side
2. Include the library as a dependency in my CMakeLists without installing it system wide.

So I have a layout like this:

```
. CMakeLists.txt
|_ src
|_ include
|_ third_party
   |_ my_library
      |_ CMakeLists.txt
      |_ src
      |_ include
```

Now the `CMakeLists.txt` in `my_library` creates some lib with `add_library()`, and it also has an `install` target which copies `libmy_library.a` to `my_library/lib`.

I would like to depend on this library in my toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`. So what I need is for the `my_library` CMake project to be built *and installed* before I try to reference the library for my own targets. I tried using `ExternalProject_Add()` for this like so:

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(MY_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/my_library)

ExternalProject_Add(my_library
    SOURCE_DIR ${MY_LIB_DIR}
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED TRUE 
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE FALSE
    BINARY_DIR ${MY_LIB_DIR}/build
)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${MY_LIB_DIR}/lib)

# find compiled lib
find_library(MY_LIB_LIBRARY my_library)

add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
add_dependencies(main my_library)  
target_link_libraries(main ${MY_LIB_LIBRARY})
```

However, this does not work since at the time cmake reads the configuration, `libmy_library.a` has not been built yet.

**The question thus: How can I make CMake build and install an external project so I can list install artifacts as dependencies?**

It has been suggested this is a duplicate, but the linked answer builds the external project inside the current project, which I find undesirable.

Comment: Is there anything specific to your setup that prevents you from just using `add_subdirectory(third_party/my_library)` ?

Comment: Unlike, say, Maven, CMake is not a dependency management tool AFAIK. It assumes that all dependencies are already present and can be located.

Comment: @Frank One reason was that both projects use `gtest` and thus there is a duplicate target.